# FlattenFields is not working as expected

Tags: itext7

We have been working on a POC with IText7 and getting an error when we try to FlattenFields. All we are trying to do is load a pdf template and inject values. The template which we are using was working fine with IText5.

Here is the exception message:
An exception of type 'iText.Kernel.PdfException' occurred in itext.kernel.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: unbalanced.begin.end.marked.content.operators

```
using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(fileName), new PdfWriter(outputStream)))
{
                PdfAcroForm stamper = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
                stamper.FlattenFields();
                stamper.SetGenerateAppearance(true);
}
```

Regards
Shreenidhi B.R

Comment: Please share the pdf

Comment: Your question is confusing: you say you are using iText 7, but your code is iText 5 code. That doesn't make any sense. There is no `PdfStamper` class in iText 7.

Comment: The PdfAcroForm instance is named stamper, it is not using PdfStamper class. On a different note, is there a way I can email the certificate to you @AmedeeVanGasse?

Comment: No, you cannot send me emails. Put the file on a public download site like Dropbox and share it. Make sure it doesn't contain confidential information.

Answer (score 0):

Followed up with IText support folks and they said that this issue has been fixed in IText 7.0.1. I haven't had a chance to test it myself though.

Comment: I am still getting the same exact issue using itex7 7.01 NuGet package. @brunolowagie